# what is a proper filter syntax for IBindingList data?

Tags: c#, filter, datatable

I have a table in my application and I designed a filter for it.
Filter works fine for numerical data however it doesnot work for text data.
I have a text column in my table that has state abbreviations (PA, LA, TX...).
But when I add a filter (see the code below), I get error that "Cannot interpret token '!'".
Any Ideas?
Thanks for the help

```
F="State != 'PA'";
IBindingListView D.filter=F;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the description [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx). `"State <> 'PA'"` and `"NOT(State = 'PA')"` should work for you.